# How to calculate position of array item?

Tags: php

I have an array with a whole bunch of badges. I have 3 variables that come from the database. I need some idea of how I can calculate the position of my $current variable to the $start and $end variables and then output as an int for a %.

Example:

```
$data = array(
     ['a','b','c'],
     ['d','e']
);

$start = 'b';
$current = 'c';
$end = 'e';

*Some maths equation to return position value?*
```

The only idea I have is I probably can count somehow how many variables are between $start and $end and somehow subtract the position of $current?

### Update

I tried your code but I think I messed up somewhere:

```
// Progress Bar configurations
$data = array(
        array('diamond_V','diamond_IV','diamond_III','diamond_II','diamond_I'),
        array('platinum_V','platinum_IV','platinum_III','platinum_II','platinum_I'),
        array('gold_V','gold_IV','gold_III','gold_II','gold_I'),
  array('silver_V','silver_IV','silver_III','silver_II','silver_I'),
  array('bronze_V','bronze_IV','bronze_III','bronze_II','bronze_I')
);

$start = $start_rank;
$current = $current_rank;
$end = $finish_rank;

foreach($data as $key => &$value){
$value = implode(",", $value);
}
$dataimplode = implode(",", $data);

$key = array_search($current, $dataimplode);
var_dump($key);
```

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp

Comment: What would your expected outcome be in this case? 3 since it's the third value?

Comment: Are the arrays of different length due to the badges being related in some way?  i.e. _`['a','b','c']`_  is: `'dibdib1' =>  ['a','b','c']`? imo, If your array index was  text then it would be easier to position at `$current`.

Comment: @RyanVincent correct yes each array is grouped as related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps

1. implode your existing array so that it looks like `array('a,b,c,d,e')`
2. To do this fist implode the inner arrays in your `$data` so that it becomes `array(['a,b,c'],['d,e'])` and then implode this array it would give you an `array('a,b,c,d,e')`
3. once you get this then using `$key = array_search($value, $array);` you can get index of your values "b","c","e"  = "2","3","5" respectively (say these numbers are saved in variables `$start`, `$current` and `$end` respectively)
4. and since you have 3 numeric values now you can easily find the % of "3" by the formula `(($current-$start)/($end-$start))*100`

Implode $data using following code snippet

```
$data = array(
    array("a","b","c"),
    array("d","e","f")
);
foreach($data as $key => &$value){
    $value = implode(",", $value);
}
$dataimplode = explode(",",(implode(",", $data)));
print_r($dataimplode);
```

Comment: If I implode data should it already do it right or how would I actually implode each one inside data?

Comment: No directly imploding $data wont work run a foreach loop on data and then implode the data Look at the updated answer after 5 minutes

Comment: I will give this a shot today and ill update the result and mark it if it works properly

Comment: Replace `implode(",", $data)` with `$dataimplode = explode(",",(implode(",", $data)));`. I have updated my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your data structure, but a generic solution would be something with nested loops:

```
$i = 0;
$startPos = -1;
$endPost = -1;
$currentPos = -1;

foreach ($data as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        if ($item == $start) $startPos = $i;
        if ($item == $current) $currentPos = $i;
        if ($item == $end) $endPos = $i;
        
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Using this code would give you and unique index of each item in the array. The calculation of the distance is then just some subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :

First get the position of every items :

- $start should be 0
- $current with array_search()
- $end with count()

then once your 3 vars are numbers it's time to do some maths.

```
($current - $start) / ($end - $start )
```

Will give you the percentage, even if you're using negative numbers (as long as $end > $current > $start).

Comment: can count() be used to not just count the entire array but between certain values?

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return an array containing `(i,j)` meaning the value `$needle` can be found on `$haystack[i][j]`. This function supports only a cascade of 2 arrays max, e.g.: array(array()).

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $some=array_search($needle,$value);
        if(is_array($value) && $some !== false){
            return array($key, $some);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The following will give you the total index given the `(i, j)` and the `$data` array. This function supports only a cascade of 2 arrays max, e.g.: array(array()).

```
function gettotalindex($index, $array)
{
    $j = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$index[0]; $i++)
    {
        $j += count($array[$i]);
    }
    $j += $index[1];
    return $j;
}
```

You can use both of these functions this way:

```
$start = gettotalindex(recursive_array_search('b', $data), $data);
```

I've joined them, though, so you'll be able to use `recursive_total_index('b', $data)` and get the total index and made it fully recursive, supporting an unlimited* number of cascades:

```
function recursive_total_index($needle, $haystack) {
    $index = 0;
    if(!is_array($haystack)) return false;
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $index += ($key>0 ? count($haystack[$key-1]) : 0);
        $some = recursive_total_index($needle,$value);
        if(is_array($value) && $some !== false){
            return $index+$some;
        }
        else if(!is_array($value) && $needle===$value)
        {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example of use:

```
$data = array( ['a','b'], ['c','d'], array(['e','f'],['g','h'], array(['i','j'])));
echo recursive_total_index('i', $data);    

*Outputs 8*
```

Then just subtract and do what you want.

Comment: But can the above return the position as an int or is it only for finding if it exists.